# While Calling Web.api getting 'Method not allowed' error'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api2

While consuming the web.Api i am getting method not allowed(405). i followed all step but issue is still there. But when I test through soapUi it works well. Please help

Web.Api Declaration:

```
 [Route("ForgotPassword")]
    [AcceptVerbs( "POST")]
    public ForgotPasswordResponse ForgotPassword(string emailId)
    {

        AccountInfo accountInfo = _manager.GetUserByEmailId(emailId);

        if (accountInfo == null)
            return new ForgotPasswordResponse
            {
                Response = "error",
                Message = "Email address not found"
            };

        return new ForgotPasswordResponse
        {
            Response = "success",
            Message = "password reset link set to registered email id"
        };
    }
```

Consuming Service call:

```
     using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://100.7.11.76");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var response12 = client.GetAsync("test.Api/api/account/ForgotPassword?EmailId=" + email + "").Result;
                if (response12.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseString = response12.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Instead of `client.GetAsync(..` it should be `client.PostAsync(..` because your `ForgotPassword` action method is accepting only **post request**.

Comment: can you give me example of client.PostAsync(), in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WebAPI controller `ForgotPasswordResponse` accepts the verb "POST" and your WebAPI client is invoking it as GET. Hence you get 406: Method not allowed response. Either make your controller accept GET verb or invoke the WebAPI using [PostAsJsonAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method instead of `GetAsync`.

Comment: I am getting 405 error, can you provide me code to call it.

Comment: client.PostAsJsonAsync("test.Api/api/account/ForgotPassword", email).Result;

Comment: I am not able to find PostAsJsonAsync method in httpclient, it says this httpclient does not contain the definition for this method, I am using 4.5 framework.

Comment: you would need to add reference of System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll. Also make sure your your WEBApi Client Nuget package is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Route` attribute to `[Route("api/account/ForgotPassword")]`, change from POST to GET and test your method from a REST client like PostMan first and then use it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Authentication Filters  [AllowAnonymous]

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("ForgotPassword")]
        [AcceptVerbs( "POST")]
        public ForgotPasswordResponse ForgotPassword(string emailId)
        {

            AccountInfo accountInfo = _manager.GetUserByEmailId(emailId);

            if (accountInfo == null)
                return new ForgotPasswordResponse
                {
                    Response = "error",
                    Message = "Email address not found"
                };

            return new ForgotPasswordResponse
            {
                Response = "success",
                Message = "password reset link set to registered email id"
            };
        }
```